# Ошибка в методе

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте.
Есть метод onCreate:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LinearLayout llBottom = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llBottom);
        TextView tvBottom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBottom);
        Button btnBottom = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBottom);

        llBottom.setBackgroundResource(R.color.llBottomColor);
        tvBottom.setText(R.string.tvBottomText);
        btnBottom.setText(R.string.btnBottomText);
    }
```

Подчеркивает "R.color.llBottomColor" и пишет "Expected resourse of type drawable". Но приложение запускается нормально. Что это значит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ложное срабатывание `lint`'а.

Answer (score 1):

Метод setBackgroundResource() принимает в себя ссылку на ресурс типа Drawable, вы же ему передаёте ресурс типа Color. Поменяйте метод на setBackgroundColor(), например.

Comment: `setBackgroundResource()` так же принимает и `R.color.*`, преобразуя результат к `ColorDrawable`.

Comment: @falstaf

Из описания метода: "Set the background to a given resource. The resource should refer to a Drawable object or 0 to remove the background."
А так да, можно и Color ему передать.

Comment: @falstaf Так а сделать то что нужно?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, да, это неточность документации. Зато это поведение хорошо расписано в документации на `Resources.getDrawable()`, который, собственно, и используется в `View.setBackgroundResource()`.

Comment: @compl, проигнорировать. Или добавить соответствующую `@SuppressWarnings` аннотацию. Это ложное срабатывание, что тут ещё сделать-то?